# Error in using pointer to structure

Tags: c

My code here gives me compile time error - "dereferencing pointer to a incomplete type"  in the function InsertList. Iam unable to figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct ListNode;
struct ListNode{
int data;
struct ListNode* next;
};

void main(int argc,char* argv[]){

int p;
FILE *ptr;
FILE *out;

//ptr=fopen("C:\Users\dheeraj\Desktop\input.txt","r");
out=fopen("output.txt","w");

struct Listnode* head=0;

while(fscanf(ptr,"%d",&p) != EOF){
InsertList(head,p);
}
close(ptr);
}

void InsertList(struct Listnode** headref,int data)
{

struct Listnode* newNode= malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
if(newNode == 0)
    printf("Memory error\n");

newNode->data=data;
newNode->next = (*headref);
(*headref )=newNode;

}
```

Comment: `InsertList(head,p);` ---> `InsertList(&head,p);`

Comment: Please paste the error message _exactly_ as it appears.  It may help answers provide answers better, and it will help future users find the question more easily.  The typo in "dereferencing pointer to a inomplete type" (inomplete instead of incomplete) will make it harder for a user to find this question, even if they have _exactly_ the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void InsertList(struct Listnode** headref,int data)
```

should be:

```
void InsertList(struct ListNode** headref,int data)
```

Also:

```
struct Listnode* newNode= malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

should be:

```
struct ListNode* newNode= malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

Do a global search for `Listnode` and replace with `ListNode`.

Comment: Oh,thank you so much, such a silly mistake, spent so much time trying so many things.